# Update Apollo cache after Mutation

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo

I try to update Apollo cache after running Mutation. For this, i use `mutate` method :

```
client.mutate({
  mutation: CREATE_PLAYLIST,
  variables: { ...playlistUpdated, users: [1] },
  update: cache => {
    const { playlists } = cache.readQuery({ query: GET_USER_PLAYIST });

    cache.writeQuery({
      query: GET_USER_PLAYIST,
      data: { playlists: playlists.concat(playlistUpdated) }
    });
  }
});
```

But on `writeQuery` function, i've this error : `TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.playlists')`. I'm not really understand why i've this error because data.playlists exist on `GET_USER_PLAYIST` query response :/

```
const GET_USER_PLAYIST = gql`
  {
    playlists(where: { users: { id: 1 } }) {
      name
      id
    }
  }
`;
```

Anyone can help me ?

Thank you community !

Comment: Looks like a typo. When calling `writeQuery`, you're constructing an object with a `playlist` property, but it should be `playlists` based on your query.

Comment: Hi ! Mmm yes, i think it's wrong c/p, but same results with `playlists` :(

Answer (score 1):

The query you are caching has the variables:

`where: { users: { id: 1 } }`

So the in memory cache saves the query with these query variables. If you want to read / write the query you would also need to add the correct variables in

`cache.readQuery({ query: GET_USER_PLAYIST });`

`cache.writeQuery({ ... });`

Take a look at the second example in the [docu](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching/#readquery)

In youre case it should be something like:

```js
const { playlists } = client.readQuery({
  query: GET_USER_PLAYIST,
  variables: {
    where: { users: { id: 1 }} // maybe the variables need to be passed in when updating the cache
  },
});

cache.writeQuery({
  query: GET_USER_PLAYIST,
  data: {
    playlists: playlists.concat(playlistUpdated)
  },
  variables: {
    where: { users: { id: 1 }}
  }
});
```